# Another Index out of bound exception in Java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * 
 */

/**
 * @author abogal6274
 *
 */
public class TicTacToe {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
TTTBoard();

    }
    public static void TTTBoard(){

        String[][] tttBoard = new String[3][3];
         for(int i=0; i<=3;i++){
             tttBoard[i][3] = "[ ]";
         }

         System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tttBoard));
    }

}



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at TicTacToe.TTTBoard(TicTacToe.java:25)
    at TicTacToe.main(TicTacToe.java:18)
```

The thing about this is that it says this as an error. Why? I tried like making it `i<=3` , `i<4` and all stuff but I still get error. I really need help on this to finish my tic tac toe App.

**EDIT**: Thats solved but:
it prints out this: `[[null, null, [ ]], [null, null, [ ]], [null, null, [ ]]]` whitch its suppose to print but can it be vertical like a tic tac toe board?

Comment: change `for(int i=1; i<=3;i++)` to `for(int i=0; i<3;i++)`

Comment: @rajuGT Changed it but still dosent work...

Comment: tttBoard[i][3] = "[ ]"; should be tttBoard[i][2] = "[ ]";

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: @Universe Also consider Raf's suggestion. Accessing 3rd index in 3*3 array is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

`tttBoard[i-1][3]` is out of bounds regardless of `i`, due to the 3.

If you wish to initialize the entire 2D array, use a nested loop :

```
    String[][] tttBoard = new String[3][3];
    for(int i=0; i<tttBoard.length;i++)
        for(int j=0; j<tttBoard[i].length;j++)
            tttBoard[i][j] = "[ ]";
```

To print the board in 3 lines, don't use `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tttBoard));`.

You can use :

```
    for(int i=0; i<tttBoard.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<tttBoard[i].length;j++)
            System.out.print(tttBoard[i][j] + ' ');
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: @Universe Your array has 3 rows and 3 columns, so 3 is an invalid column index.

Comment: @Universe because the array range goes from `0-length-1`, which would result in `2` beeing the highest entry. In addition it looks like you would want to prepare the array for the game, which would result in 6 null entries in your array.

Comment: Wait it prints out this:[[null, null, [ ]], [null, null, [ ]], [null, null, [ ]]]  whitch its suppose to print but can it be vertical like a tic tac toe board?

Comment: Ok Ima  check that out does it print like a tic tac toe board though?

Comment: @Universe If you want to print the array in multiple lines, don't use `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tttBoard));`. Use a nested loop and print the elements of the array one by one.

Comment: @Eran And How do i do that Eran? Sorry for my many questions .

Comment: @Eran Just used your code but it dosent work since you need to put that -1 after the tttboard[i].length(); But even after i did that it just prints null

Comment: @Universe You don't need a -1. I had a typo in the condition and increment of the inner loop (should be `j` instead of `i`). fixed now

Answer (score 1):

```
String[][] tttBoard = new String[3][3];
         for(int i=1; i<=3;i++){
             tttBoard[i-1][3] = "[ ]";
         }
```

you have and array with **3 rows and 3 columns**, both from index 0, 1 and 2, but **you are trying to get the element at index 3** (the 4th element)

that is the reason of your Exception

Comment: Oooo know i understand Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you got this error because of that line `tttBoard[i-1][3] = "[ ]";`

Arrays are zero based ,if your array length is `1` then you can only reference element `0` so in your case you can reference `0,1,2`.

i think what you need is `tttBoard[i-1][2] = "[ ]";`

Answer (score 1):

The exception is because you are accessing the out of bound in two places

```
for(int i=0; i<=3;i++){
             tttBoard[i][3] = "[ ]";
         }
```

In above loop replace `i <= 3` to `i < tttBoard.length`

As well the following statement

```
tttBoard[i][3] = "[ ]";
```

3 in above causes the exception, max is 2. If you change it to `tttBoard[i][2] = "[ ]";` then you won't get exception to avoid going beyond the array bound.

Answer (score 0):

In java and most of other Programming language index counting start from `0`.

So if you have an array of length `5`
then index will be `0,1,2,3,4`.

if you have an array of length `N`

index will be `0,1,2.....N-1`.
As you have an array like:

```
String[][] tttBoard = new String[3][3]
```

so indexes will be:

```
tttBoard[0-2][0-2]

for(int i=0; i<=3;i++)
```

inside the loop what happening is:

```
tttBoard[3][anything] ----> exception 

 tttBoard[anything][3] -> exception
```